# Redirect url does not match registered redirect url in instragram

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am using this libray https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk after login we getting  one error

[image]

we created app in instrantgram like :
[image]

i have  add URL scheme to my application's plist file

[image]

how to solve this issue please help me

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Stavash redirect url does not match registered redirect url ,see my question image

Comment: Oh, sorry - missed it :)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk/issues/5

Comment: @Stavash i also checked this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got my mistake

**Redirect url** ig3213f9bbab4841aba216996a24e9138e://authorize

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly stated in the Instagram iOS SDK documentation that the URL Scheme needs to be structured as:

> > ig[clientId]://

So in your case:

> > ig3213f9b...

Will not work, try

> > ig32313...://

Answer (score 0):

You are using OAuth and you are trying to run it on browser.
What you are missing is your OAuth Token, Please check if its there when you hit the API in your code.

May be it can help you..

Comment: any other library for implementation of instagram ?

Comment: Have you checked the OAuth Token...
Please check these API if they can help you...
https://github.com/Buza/Instagram-Auth-iOS
https://github.com/wfleming/WFInstagramAPI

Comment: i check this https://github.com/Buza/Instagram-Auth-iOS no display login screen thank for reply

Answer (score 0):

set the call back url like this:[image]